# LocalSystem vs. System vs. Local System Windows system accounts

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows, networking, system

I am completely confused by MS docs on Windows built-in accounts.

[SQL Server 2008 R2 online docs "Setting Up Windows Service Accounts"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx) tells

> "**Local System** is a very
>   high-privileged built-in account. It
>   has extensive privileges on the local
>   system and acts as the computer on the
>   network. **The actual name of the
>   account is "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM**".

while MSDN article "LocalSystem Account", see the link in comments, dated by 8/5/2010, tells:

> The **LocalSystem** account is a
>   predefined local account used by the
>   service control manager. This account
>   is not recognized by the security
>   subsystem, so you cannot specify its
>   name in a call to the
>   LookupAccountName function. It has
>   extensive privileges on the local
>   computer, and acts as the computer on
>   the network. **Its token includes the NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and
>   BUILTIN\Administrators SIDs**; these
>   accounts have access to most system
>   objects. **The name of the account in
>   all locales is .\LocalSystem. The
>   name, LocalSystem or
>   ComputerName\LocalSystem** can also be
>   used. This account does not have a
>   password. If you specify the
>   LocalSystem account in a call to the
>   CreateService function, any password
>   information you provide is ignored

Now, looking on my Windows XP Pro SP3 (part of workgroup) with installed MS SQL Server 2008 R2 x86 Trial (Developer Preview) into available accounts:

Windows Explorer dir right-Click --> Properties --> Security tab --> btn "Add..." -->  btn "Advanced..." --> btn "Find Now..."

reveals that Windows XP has  neither "NT Authority\SYSTEM", nor "Local System", nor LocalSystem but has only  SYSTEM account.

How should I understand and read MS docs? One article after another contradicting each another and having nothing in common with observed reality

### ----------

**Edit1:**

Oops, I cannot even continue discussion and edit my post recieving:  "new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink. Earn 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks".

Though I am not a new user and points are never being added to my account upon answering, posting, etc., as described in FAQ!

Comment: The link to cited MSDN article "LocalSystem Account" is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: I could not post more thn one link recieving "new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink. Earn 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks", though I am not the new user!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asked and answered on Server Fault. http://serverfault.com/questions/168752/windows-localsystem-vs-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the same question answered
https://serverfault.com/questions/168752/windows-localsystem-vs-system

Answer (score 0):

I believe the confusion comes from the fact that they are differentiating the local account (created and existing on the computer itself) from any possible account named SYSTEM in the domain, if you are attached to one. Thus, they say **LOCAL** SYSTEM account.

Comment: Well, they say 1) "Local System" = "NT Authority\System" and 2)LocalSystem token includes SIDs of "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" and "BUILTIN\Administrators".  My Windows XP Pro SP3 does not have any "Local System" or LocalSystem. My Windows XP Pro is part of workgroup, no domain. All MS docs, forum discussions are about "Local System". How should I understand/read them?