# How do i set Identity of COM+ server type application to Network Service in power shell

Tags: powershell, com

I need to do the following thing.

Create com+ application -> set activation type to Server type-> set identity as Network service->Add user group under creater owner.

I am able to set activation type,but i am not able to set identity and the further steps.
I am new to com+ applications.
 the script i have written is as follows

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
$apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection(“Applications”)
$apps.Populate();

$newComPackageName = “test7”

$appExistCheckApp = $apps | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $newComPackageName}

if($appExistCheckApp)
{
$appExistCheckAppName = $appExistCheckApp.Value(“Name”)
“This COM+ Application already exists : $appExistCheckAppName”
}
Else
{
$newApp1 = $apps.Add()
$newApp1.Value(“Name”) = $newComPackageName
$newApp1.value("Activation") = 1
$newApp1.Value("identity").Access="NT AUTHORITY\system"
$newApp1.Value("Password") = ""

$saveChangesResult = $apps.SaveChanges()
“Results of the SaveChanges operation : $saveChangesResult”
}
```

The error i am getting is Identity value is not correct.
Please help :)

Comment: You should not set the password at all. Otherwise, have you tried LocalSystem or other names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439760/localsystem-vs-system-vs-local-system-windows-system-accounts

Comment: There is a typo. I think $newApp1.value("Activation") should be an uppercase 'v': $newApp1.Value("Activation")

Answer (score 2):

You probably fixed this at this point already, but I believe the issue could be 1 of 2 things, depending on the error you are receiving.

1. The identity or password is not valid - so just make sure you are using valid credentials.
2. It could be an invalid parameter. In that case I believe changing the 'identity' to 'Identity' and it should work fine. For example:

`$newApp1.Value("Identity") ="DOMAIN\username"
    $newApp1.Value("Password") = "password"`